# After button click timer should start again

Tags: button, таймер, click

This is my code for the timer and it should restart after button click whose id is #timer from 60 seconds. I did many things but it won't work. Please help.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    const FULL_DASH_ARRAY = 283;
    const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
    const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

    const COLOR_CODES = {
        info: {
            color: "green"
        },
        warning: {
            color: "orange",
            threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD
        },
        alert: {
            color: "red",
            threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD
        }
    };

    const TIME_LIMIT = 60;
    let timePassed = 0;
    let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
    let timerInterval = null;
    let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;

    document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
    <div class="base-timer">
    <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g class="base-timer__circle">
        <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
        <path
            id="base-timer-path-remaining"
            stroke-dasharray="283"
            class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
            d="
            M 50, 50
            m -45, 0
            a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
            a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
            "
        ></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
        timeLeft 
    )}</span>
    </div>
    `;

    $('#timer').click( function() {
        startTimer();
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    })

    function startTimer() {
        timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
            timePassed = timePassed += 1;
            timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
            document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
            timeLeft
            );
            setCircleDasharray();
            setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

            if (timeLeft <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timerInterval);
                $('#timer').removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    function formatTime(time) {
    let seconds = time % 60;

    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = `${seconds}`;
    }

    return `${seconds}`;
    }

    function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
    const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
    if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
        document
        .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .classList.remove(warning.color);
        document
        .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .classList.add(alert.color);
    } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
        document
        .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .classList.remove(info.color);
        document
        .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .classList.add(warning.color);
    }
    }

    function calculateTimeFraction() {
    const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
    return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
    }

    function setCircleDasharray() {
    const circleDasharray = `${(
        calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY
    ).toFixed(0)} 283`;
    document
        .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
    }

});

</script>текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом

<div id="app"></div>
<button  class="button" id="timer">Начать обратный отсчет</button>
```

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский, в метках к вопросу укажите язык программирования/используемые технологии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function startTimer() {

    timePassed = 0;
    clearInterval(timerInterval);

    timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
        timePassed += 1;
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, everything works :)

Comment: @OlyaUs Pleasure is mine.